# Textarea value becoming "\n" when i set its value to "" in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

After some process I set the value of textarea '' but in dom i found its value '\n'. Thats why placeholder does not appear. Have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Im using this.value = "" to set the value; but it contains '\n'; i can access the value and want to change it to "" so that placeholder appear again

Answer (score 1):

[It works](http://jsbin.com/hesodumu/1/edit?js,console,output).

JS:

```
function onclickfunc(){
    var $area = $("#area");
    console.log($area.val());
    $area.val("");
    console.log($area.val());
}
```

Output:

```
"Hello World!"
""
```

See there's new line in the second log.

Comment: Does your placeholder appear of $area after removing its value. Its not working for me

Comment: Here's the box with placeholder. http://jsbin.com/hesodumu/2/edit

Comment: I hav found the problem I have done this at enter keypress thats why a '\n' always appear. thank you @HighBoots